# HttpWebRequest throws an exception when sending a request via HTTPS in Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, compact-framework, httpwebresponse

I am trying to get data from a web service which works on SSL so it works in https://www.abc.com. But it gives an exception:

> System.Net.WebException: Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection.  System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Unknown error (0x0).

I tried [this help file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970549), and also downloaded the cab file and installed it again, but still got the same error.

Comment: Hi UnhandledException, Is this problem in currently in R&D?